# Adobe Presenter CMI Data Model

Tags: asp.net, adobe, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I want to build an e-learning LMS using `Adobe Presenter 7` as content authoring tools. I recently read the SCORM 2004 user guide. It says we have to access CMI data model to track user performance. But, I can't find any files with name containing **cmi** in the zip file the Adobe Presenter 7 created.
Any idea where I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the RTE book to understand the CMI data model. CMI data model is NOT a file in the content package. It is a data model provided by the LMS. In fact, the SCO can communicate with LMS through the use of this data model elements. For example, the SCO can get learner's name with the following JavaScript code:

var learnerName = GetValue("cmi.learner_name");

Or, the SCO can set the activity's success status to passed with the following JavaScript code:

SetValue("cmi.success_status", "passed");

You can download the RTE book with the following link:

http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_Doc_Suite.zip

Comment: thanks for the answer. It will really take a long time to finish the book. But I think it will help me to understand CMI data model.

Comment: Note that CMI data model is another name for Run-Time Environment data model, @aswin.